# Select only the columns which are not equal in both tables

Tags: sql, database, join, db2

**How I can query the database to find only the columns which are not equal in both tables we are comparing?**

For example.

TableA :

```
Name   Age   City   State 
John   32    xxx    xxx
Joe    45    yyy    yyy
Mark   22    zzz    zzz
```

TableB :

```
Name   Age   City   State
John   32    xxx    xxx
Joe    45    yyy    yyy
Mark   21    zzz    zzz
```

I want to select only the column values where they are different from TableB.
Where Same Name, Age, State but the City is different.

For example Mark is turned 22 and I need to update his age in TableB. So I need my query to find out only the column where there is need for an update. In the above case, it should return me the Age column for only Mark's record.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Name,T1.Age,T1.State,T1.City as City1,T2.City as City2
FROM TableA T1, TableB T2
WHERE T1.Age=T2.Age 
     AND T1.Name=T2.Name
     AND T1.State=T2.State
     AND T1.City<>T2.City
```

Comment: It is giving the Cartesian product which is not an option at all. I'm trying to find out the way, where if Name is different from tableB's name column -> select Name. If state is different from tableB's state column -> select state. If city is same as tableB's city column then don't select city. So only select the range of columns which are not exactly the same as in table B. Thanks.

Comment: @Superman: You mean a join? Is there any primary key and foreign key? Can you show a sample result you are looking for?

Comment: @RagingBull - the comma-separated `FROM` clause is an _implicit_ (and usually `INNER`) join.  Agree that we need more info from the question.

Comment: @Superman: Did my answer get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the correct answer.

Comment: @RagingBull I'm sorry for late reply. My question was about to determine this at run time. Instead of just comparing each column by value. It is like that tableA has 10 records and tableB has 10 records. We'll compare both tables on the base of some key. And I suppose the query to return me only the column name in the result which is different from tableA's any column. So there is no fix comparison between both tables except a key we passed. Rest of the thing should have to be done by DB.

Comment: @RagingBull I edit my question with an example of data. Please have a look.

Comment: @RagingBull For example Mark is turned 22 and I need to update his age in TableB. So I need my query to find out only the column where there is need for an update. In the above case, it should return me the Age column for only Mark's record.